# Find value of $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

For what value of $k$, are the roots of the quadratic equation
$$(k+4)x^2 + (k+1)x +1 = 0$$ equal.

Comment: i tried b^2-4ac=0

Comment: Well, that's correct. Have more faith in yourself

Comment: I second @IshanBanerjee, the best way to be a Learner is to try and do it, you're nearly there, go on!

Answer (score 6):

Roots are equal, when the discriminant of this quadratic equation is zero.

$D = (k+1)^2-4(k+4)$

$0 = (k+1)^2-4(k+4) = k^2 - 2k - 15$

there  are two solutions: $k = -3$  and $k = 5$